# Parse isoutcdatetime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to parse isoutcdatetime **"2011-03-18T00:00:00Z"** to get **"2011-03-18"**. Anyone knows how to parse it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want the substring, which isn't parsing:

```
var dateString = "2011-03-18T00:00:00Z".substring(0, 10));
```

Comment: I worry that if we substring like this it is not a general rule to get only date from isoutcdatetime. any more ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript