# javascript date.parse difference in chrome and other browsers

Tags: javascript

I have a date string "2011-11-24T09:00:27+0000" fetched from the graph.facebook API.

When I run

```
var timestamp = Date.parse(facebookDate);
```

in chrome. I get a timestamp that relates to the date! perfect!

But in EVERY other major browser... I get "NaN" !!! ?

Surely all these browsers use the same javascript parse function right?

Can anybody explain why the same javascript function give different results?

And can anybody also tell me how to fix this issue...

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: Please see updated script since the first one ADDED the offset instead of subtracting it.

Comment: "Surely all these browsers use the same javascript parse function right?" No. Welcome to Web Development.

Comment: @Alex - is it ALWAYS +0000 because then we can just change it to Z

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a fix for Firefox and IE/Safari (with the help from [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par)
 ) :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QkasD/)

```
var noOffset = function(s) {
  var day= s.slice(0,-5).split(/\D/).map(function(itm){
    return parseInt(itm, 10) || 0;
  });
  day[1]-= 1;
  day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));  
  var offsetString = s.slice(-5)
  var offset = parseInt(offsetString,10)/100;
  if (offsetString.slice(0,1)=="+") offset*=-1;
  day.setHours(day.getHours()+offset);
  return day.getTime();
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

JavaScript 1.8.5 note

A subset of ISO 8601 formatted date strings can now also be parsed.

Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. Starting with JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4, a subset of ISO 8601 is supported. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date and time) can be passed and parsed. Timezones in ISO dates are not yet supported, so e.g. "2011-10-10T14:48:00+0200" (with timezone) does not give the intended result yet.