# regexp Parsing ISO-8601

Tags: javascript, regex, date

As a followup to a question I am trying to help with: [javascript date.parse difference in chrome and other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266710/javascript-date-parse-difference-in-chrome-and-other-browsers/8266880#8266880)

I need assistance in updating the regex I found here:

[JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5805595/295783)

to handle `2011-11-24T09:00:27+0200`

It currently only is supposed to handle the `2011-11-24T09:00:27Z` version of the ISO date

i.e. the rx in

```
function(s){
    var day, tz, 
    rx= /^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/, 
    p= rx.exec(s) || [];
    if(p[1]){
        day= p[1].split(/\D/).map(function(itm){
            return parseInt(itm, 10) || 0;
        });
        day[1]-= 1;
        day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
        if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
        if(p[5]){
            tz= parseInt(p[5], 10)*60;
            if(p[6]) tz += parseInt(p[6], 10);
            if(p[4]== "+") tz*= -1;
            if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
        }
        return day;
    }
    return NaN;
}
```

to make [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QkasD/) work with IE and Safari

---

UPDATE: The answers worked. Now I can help others parse the ISO date returned from the facebook API.

Comment: What have you tried? This site should not be to get free work done for you.

Comment: +1: must say this is an unnecessary down vote!

Comment: @Evert Seems like a reasonable question to me. He's a 10k user with hundreds of answers, so I think your comment is a bit unfair.

Comment: 10K doesn't mean he won't make a mistake :) Every time I open the unanswered page, there's a lot of 'write a regex for me'-type of questions. I tend to downvote those.

Comment: @Evert - what have I tried? Trying to help another SO user, I obviously have a) found the code that almost worked, b) created a fiddle and changed it to handle Firefox, c) figured out the regex for IE and Safari did not work on that particular string and d) asked SO community for help in ADDING 4 more chars to the regex. If you do not feel like helping, fine - feel free to IGNORE this question. If I knew perfectly how to do it, I would not ask for help!

Comment: @mplungjan, `2011-11-24T09:00:27+002` is not valid according to the referred standard. The time offset should be 2 or 4 digits, not 3. What does `+002` mean, `+02` or `+0020` (`+00:20`)? I'm guessing the first one. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Qtax - Must have been a typo. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @mplungjan, if it's a typo remove the `\d?` in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make it work with dates of the format `2011-11-24T09:00:27+0200` simply add a `?` after the last `:`, eg:

```
/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):?(\d\d))?$/
```

Explained:

```
  (
    \d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d     # date
    ([tT][\d:\.]*)?       # optional time
  )
  (
    [zZ]                  # UTC time zone
    |                     # or
    ([+\-])               # offset sign
    (\d\d)                # hour offset
    :?                    # optional delimiter
    (\d\d)                # minute offset
  )?                      # time zone is optional
```

Rest of the code shouldn't need any changes, and all previously supported formats by the function will still work (unlike the previous answer, which breaks four digit offsets).

Comment: It would be +0200 - it was a typo

Comment: @mplungjan, updated the answer to reflect your changed question. Sadly `/x` isn't supported in JavaScript, but you can use it in most other flavors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want but your regex is wrong, try changing the end so it looks like this `/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d{3}))?$/` and it will at least match what you're looking for.

The original regex looked for a char, either `z` or `Z`, or a `+` or a `-` followed by 2 digits, a colon and then 2 more digits, I changed it so instead of looking for 2 digits, a colon and 2 more digits it looked for 3 digits as you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I can help others. It is a useful script since it handles the ISO date returned from the Facebook API.

Comment: This breaks previously supported formats. Eg. `2011-11-24T09:00:27+02` would no longer parse.

Comment: I wish I could split the answer.

Comment: @mplungjan no problem, Qtax answer was better anyway, that is why I gave it +1