# JavaScript / Extjs - Calculate number of hours from time stamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have this time stamp format for each car in my map:

```
2012-12-11T03:51:43+03:00
```

I want to extract the number of hours from it according to current time.

I don't know how to parse this string then compare it to current time.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Just to add to Yoshi's answer, you might look at using a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) for the parsing part, since even IE8 won't parse that string.

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
var
  d1 = new Date('2012-12-11T03:51:43+03:00'),
  d2 = new Date;

console.log(
  (d2 - d1) / 3600000
);
```

Comment: @ Yoshi: No, actually, since you're doing the date math, it'll using milliseconds-since-the-epoch and the timezones should fall out.

Comment: But do beware that not all browsers support parsing that date string. That format was only introduced in ES5 (so, about three years ago) and doesn't work on older browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, that may be for I did only check chrome.

Comment: Could be fixed with some regex find/replace.

Comment: @SalmanA: No, you'd be better off properly parsing it. If you do the regex thing, you'll A) be off into unspecified territory, and B) *probably* be working in the local timezone (again, though unspecified).

Comment: I'm with T.J.Crowder here, if the target platform does not allow parsing the string like this, I would not even try to fix that, and instead go for a completely different solution.

Comment: @mplungjan: You shouldn't need to do anything to it for Firefox (I don't). IE8, though, will fail, as will earlier versions.

Comment: I am talking about transforming the string `'2012-12-11T03:51:43+03:00'` into `2012-12-11 03:51:43 GMT+03:00`. Should work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fix the timestamp for other browsers than Chrome

[javascript date.parse difference in chrome and other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266880/295783)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jfK8G/)

```
var noOffset = function(s) {
  var day= s.slice(0,-5).split(/\D/).map(function(itm){
    return parseInt(itm, 10) || 0;
  });
  day[1]-= 1;
  day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));  
  var offsetString = s.slice(-5)
  var offset = parseInt(offsetString,10)/100;
  if (offsetString.slice(0,1)=="+") offset*=-1;
  day.setHours(day.getHours()+offset);
  return day.getTime();
}
alert(parseInt((new Date().getTime()-noOffset(yourTimeStamp))/3600000))
```