# Difference between desktop and mobile Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, google-chrome

This below code runs perfectly on desktop Chrome, but doesn't return the countdown properly on mobile Chrome (iPhone). Checked in Safari too, same result. It's a simple `jQuery` countdown. The script itself runs since the `innerHTML` is set after all, just with not the proper data. Also, I confirmed that `getTime()` is also correct. What can possibly be the difference?

Desktop

[image]

Mobile
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
var countDownDate = new Date(obj.getAttribute('value'));

var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  obj.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    obj.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine on the latest Chrome on Android, version: `66.0.3359.158`. I don't have a Iphone so I cannot test it. Which version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in my Chrome iPhone - yours does not.

Also tested on Windows Chrome. See [javascript date.parse difference in chrome and other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266710/javascript-date-parse-difference-in-chrome-and-other-browsers) for another version for this format `2011-11-24T09:00:27+0000`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date(obj.getAttribute('value').replace(/-/g, "/"));

    var x = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      obj.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        obj.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```