# Javascript invalid date on Android 2.2 browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

I'm getting an invalid date exception on Android 2.2 default browser with the following date format. It is valid on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Explorer.

```
>var date = new Date('1985-07-10T22:00:00.000Z')
>date.toString()
"Thu Jul 11 1985 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)"
```

I know how to parse it manually but I'd like to avoid that. Where does the issue come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing ISO dates in different browsers does not work consistently. [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par/5803041#5803041)