# Internet Explorer, Json.Net JavaScript date and milliseconds issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, datetime, json.net

I'm not sure if it's me missing something - or IE or Json.Net.

But basically this works:

`new Date("2012-08-03T12:36:54.743Z")`

This fails with 'Invalid Date' error:

`new Date("2012-08-03T12:36:54.74Z")`

The second date is stored in SQL Server as:

`2012-08-03 12:36:54.740`

It is then serialised as JSON using Json.Net - Json.Net did serialised the date as `2012-08-03T12:36:54.74Z`, effectively chopping off the last 0.

My question(s):

- Is this an intended behavior in IE - that it needs to have all 3 digits in the milliseconds bit to work ?
- Is this an intended behavior in Json.Net - that it'll always chop off the last 0 in a date ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't tell you whether it is intended or not, but I've done a lot of searching and I haven't found a real solution for this issue neither. It seems that we have to accept the fact that IE only accepts exactly three digits. The only way (for me) to get around this issue is to use a custom converter for Json.NET when serializing:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    whatEver,
    new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fffK"
        }
    );
```

*(only tested with Json.NET 4.0.8 and 4.5.8)*

This forces Json.NET to use exactly 3 decimal places.

As far as I can tell, Json.NET serializes `DateTime` values in ISO format with the maximum necessary precision omitting trailing zeroes in the decimal places of the "second" value.

This matches the output of

```
someDateTimeValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.FFFFFFFK")
```

- A normal `DateTime` like `DateTime.UtcNow` will be serialized with up to 7 digits, because that is the precision of a `DateTime` (measured in Ticks).
- If the "second" part of the `DateTime` has less decimal places, Json.NET omits those trailing zeroes.
- A date value like `DateTime.Today` will therefore contain *no* digits behind the "second" value because it is exactly `0`.

[See also this description of custom date and time format strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#FFFFFFF_Specifier)

Comment: I have the same issue using the new ASP.NET Web API. Do you know of a way to configure JSON.Net once so that this is done throughout the app?

Comment: You can specify the `IsoDateTimeConverter` as default in your `GlobalConfiguration`. Open your `Global.asax.cs`, and add something like this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fffK" });`

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for:)

Comment: Godly answer, especially the JsonFormatter fix. Thanks, @fero!

Answer (score 1):

It's IE. The most comprehensive explaination and answer I found is at [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par?rq=1)

In particular

> IE9 was failing on milliseconds with digit counts other than 3: (fixed in IE10)