# How Breeze's WebApi Controller works with UTC DateTime?

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm having a problem in the settings of Breeze's `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`.
What I would do is that the date of json sent and received by WebAPI
always work in UTC.

According to [this document](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/date-time), it would be possible by setting the property `DateTimeZoneHandling` to `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` for the `JsonSerializerSettings`

However that did not work.

Investigating [this source code](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi/JsonFormatter.cs), I realized that what might be influencing this behavior was the hack that was done for [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789114/internet-explorer-json-net-javascript-date-and-milliseconds-issue).

By removing all this code bellow, everything works ok.

```
    //jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
    //{
    //    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fffK"
    //});
```

How can I handle this situation without having to remove the Hack?

**EDIT 1**

My first attempt to set was as follows:

```
var jsonFormatter = Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatter.Create();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
jsonFormatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(
          0, jsonFormatter);
```

But this did not work, the returned date was not in UTC.

**EDIT 2**

First, I've updated the Breeze lib to 0.80.3 version.

In my  App_Start folder I have this BreezeWebApiConfig.cs file:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(Partner.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
namespace Partner.App_Start
{
    public static class BreezeWebApiConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBreezePreStart()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "BreezeApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );

            var jsonFormatter = Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatter.Create();
            jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
            jsonFormatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(false, true));

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(
                0, jsonFormatter);

            // Apply query parameters, expressed as OData URI query strings, 
            // to results of Web API controller methods that return IQueryable<T>
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
                new Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

Second, I've created a CustomBreezeConfig.cs class (with the code described below by Jay) in a folder that I called BreezeConfig, but this new attempt did not work.

Regards,

Bernardo Pacheco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try breeze v 0.80.5 along with the corresponding release notes.  Hopefully, 'time's should now roundtrip properly.

Comment: Please let us know if this solved it. If so, please check the checkmark under the answer. Doing so will help us close this issue. Thx.

Comment: @Jay I've kept the same code (the BreezeWebApiConfig.cs class described above and the CustomBreezeConfig.cs class) and updated to v 0.80.5. However, the json date sent by the server to the client is still not in UTC (without the Z at the end). Regards.

Comment: Bernardo, it won't be BUT it will get converted correctly on the client (to a UTC date)  That's what the DataType.parseDateFromServer method does.  So look at the date in the result returned in the then call.

Answer (score 2):

As of breeze v 0.80.3, we've added the capability to customize the json serializer settings that breeze uses for both queries and saves.  It involves adding a server side class that is a subclass of the new Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig class.  This subclass will look something like:

```
 public class CustomBreezeConfig : Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig {

    /// <summary>
    /// Overriden to create a specialized JsonSerializer implementation that uses UTC date time zone handling.
    /// </summary>
    protected override JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings() {
      var baseSettings = base.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
      baseSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
      return baseSettings;
    }
  }
```

Any instance of a subclass of Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig that appears in the server side project will now be automatically discovered and used to customize breeze's configuration.

Please let us know if this helps ( or doesn't ).

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for the fix, but unfortunately it did not work. I edited my question with the code I'm using so you see if I'm doing something wrong. The date in json sent from client to server is properly on UTC, but the json date sent from the server to the client is not in UTC. For example, the date sent from the server to the client would have to be 2012-12-28T00:00:00.000Z, instead of 2012-12-28T00:00:00.000. Regards.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what is happening.  It turns out that EF / SQL server does not store timezone information, so when you store a time on EF and later retrieve it, the retrieved datatime has its timezone set to 'unspecified'.  When this is then sent back to the javascript client there is no timezone information available to send (hence the missing 'Z').  It turns out that IE and Chrome interpret a missing timezone specifier as representing a UTC date, whereas Firefox interprets the same thing as a local date.  I am guessing that you are using Firefox.  Is this correct?

Comment: Continuing the previous comment.  Please confirm if this makes sense.  We are looking now at adding a setting that will indicate to breeze whether you want dates returned from the server to be treated as UTC dates or a local dates. UTC dates will be the default.

Answer (score 1):

When you say adding DateTimeZoneHandling didn't work, how did you try setting it?

You might try just adding this line immediately above the 'Converters.Add' call (from above) in the source (without removing the 'hack'), and let me know if it works.

```
 jsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

I agree that it's still clumsy because it means that you have to modify the breeze source.  So if it does work, we will try to come up with some way to allow you to set this from outside the formatter. Please let us know.

Comment: The latest [BreezeController] attribute in GitHub should make easier to deliver your formatter to the controller. That attribute will be released and appear in NuGet packages soon. That improvement doesn't make it easier for you to extend the Breeze JsonFormatter. You'll have to write one of those yourself. Fortunately, the minimum Breeze requirements are few and so re-implementing that component yourself is not **too** hard.

Comment: @Jay Hi Jay, I've edited my question with my first attempt to set DateTimeZoneHandling. I've tried to do what you said, but the returned date was not in UTC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If when you say 'returned' you mean 'returned' to the server, not the client then I do understand the issue.  Breeze currently uses two serializers, one for queries and one for saves.  The customization I gave you above is for serializing from the 'server' to the 'client', to customize the save serialization you will need to hack the source in the 'ContextProvider.saveChanges' method to use a custom json serializer.  We will try to make this pluggable in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the utc problem with this hack, which still smells.

in app.vm.run.js

```
app.vm.run = (function ($, ko, dataservice, router) {
var currentRunId = ko.observable(),
    // run will be an entity
    run = ko.observable(),
...
   save = function () {
        this.run().lastUpdate(makeDatetimeUTC(moment().toDate()));
        this.run().runStart(makeDatetimeUTC(this.run().runStart()));
        this.run().runEnd(makeDatetimeUTC(this.run().runEnd()));
        dataservice.saveChanges();
        // the test r === run() succeeds because the local run is a 
        //  ko.observable which is bound to the run in the cache
        var r = dataservice.getRunById(currentRunId());
    },
...

})($, ko, app.dataservice, app.router);
```

in myScripts.js

```
// Here is a real pain in the neck.
//  For some reason, when the entity is saved, it shows up on the server as UTC datetime
//  instead of local.  Moment parses everything as local by default, so the formatDate function
//  used to get a display value needs to be converted to utc before it is returned to the server.
// 
// This function takes the value of the dependentObservable in the entity
//  and converts it to a string which can be stored back into the entity before sending
//  it to the server.
//
// The reason I need to do that is so that it displays properly after the save.      
//  The date seems to be handled properly by the server.

var makeDatetimeUTC = function(localDatetime) {
    var datestring = formatDate(localDatetime);
    var utc = moment.utc(datestring);
    return formatDate(utc);
};

var formatDate = function(dateToFormat) {
    if (dateToFormat === null ||dateToFormat === undefined || dateToFormat.length === 0)
        return "";

    // intermediate variable is not needed, but is good for debugging
    var formattedDate = moment(dateToFormat).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A');
    return formattedDate;
    },
    formatObservableDate = function(observable) {
        if (ko.isObservable(observable))
            return observable(formatDate(observable()));
        else
            throw new Error("formatObservableDate expected a ko.Observable ");
    };
```