# Local DateTime with Breeze Queries

Tags: breeze

I am trying to figure out how to deal with an application database that has all DateTimes stored as local times, with users in different time zones using breeze.

My problem is very similar to this:
[How we survive using a local time zone with Breeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261652/how-we-survive-using-a-local-time-zone-with-breeze)

The only major difference is that I'd like for all dates over the wire to be in ISO8601 UTC, and for all dates on the server to be treated as and serialzed to/from local, since this is what is in the database.

My problem comes in when querying with date filters using breeze. The database is queried using UTC times that are not converted to local, producing incorrect results. The "Solution 2" from the linked thread looked to be the most promising to fix this, but it doesn't work, for me at least. It seems to have no effect on the generated query that is issued to the database. I've stepped through some of the BreezeController code, and from what I can tell, the problem is somewhere within System.Web.Http.OData.

So, how to use breeze with a distributed user base, and a database that is storing all DateTime values in local server time?

Thanks for your help,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using BreezeConfig to customize the JSON.Net serialization of datetimes.  There are several other Breeze related posts that describe this.