# Firefox returning invalid for timezone offsets?

Tags: javascript, firefox, datetime, timezone

I've come across what appears to be an odd result from Firefox. Using the following format:

```
2013/01/01 00:00:00-0000
```

For my date, I run into an issue when the timezone goes "positive". For example.

```
new Date('2013/01/01 05:00:00-0000')
Date { Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) }
```

But.

```
new Date('2013/01/01 05:00:00+0100')
Date { Invalid Date }
```

I would expect rather to get:

Date { Mon Dec 31 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) }

It appears the `+` is what causes the problems, which seems to be a pretty big issue if I can't use timezones east of GMT.

EDIT: added a http://jsfiddle.net/utm4f/

Run in Firefox and it will return an invalid date (I am running Firefox 20 on OS X 10.8.3)

Comment: Which version of Firefox exactly are you using? And do you have confirmed that it does work for negative offsets (you've shown `0` only)?

Comment: FF 20.0. Yes, I've tried by using the FF console. -0200, -0300, etc... all work, as soon as you try +0100 it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the issue by throwing whatever I can at it. Apparently Firefox requires a space between the time and timezone.

```
new Date('2013/01/01 05:00:00 +0100')
new Date('2013/01/01 05:00:00 -0100')
```

The `-` timezones won't error without a space, but the `+` ones will.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ISO8601 values instead, such as:

```
2013-12-31T01:23:45-07:00
```

Parsing of ISO dates will work on all newer browsers, but fail on some older ones, most notably IE8.  There is an excellent description of the browser support for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802461/634824), as well as a shim for older browser support.

But if you really want to support all of the inconsistencies in different browsers, the best way (IMHO) is with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
var m = moment('2013-12-31T01:23:45-07:00');
```

Or even using your other format, with an explicit parsing string:

```
var m = moment('2013/01/01 00:00:00-0000', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ssZZ');
```