# IE javascript Engine rending NaN when conveting string to date

Tags: javascript

I have a string consisting of '2013-04-05T00:00:00'. When I embed the below code into my js file Chakra (IE javascript engine) barfs. When I run this from the IE console it barfs. Every other browser I have tested on is fine. How can i make the below statement browser agnostic?

```
var targetDate = new Date('2013-04-05T00:00:00');
alert(targetDate);
```

EDIT 
IE version 7,8 does not run

runs fine in ie 9+

EDIT#2

The reason this doesn't work is that IE 8,7 do not support ISO date times. You will either need to generate a Date object from a non ISO date time stamp.

Comment: Any IE or any specific version?

Comment: This looks like some ISO 8601 date string. I think that JS engines aren't supposed to parse this (even if they do).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par

Comment: ISO dates require > IE8; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @dystroy: It's the other way round. ES5 engines are supposed to parse it, but IE<9 does not do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to *fix up* these Date parsing issues.  This will work in IE8:

```
<html>
   <body>
   <script src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
      var targetDate = Date.parse('2013-04-05T00:00:00');
      alert(targetDate);
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note, you'll have to use the `Date.parse` method rather than the `Date()` constructor.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upB6h/)