# What is the most compatible javascript time format for Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I have a time stamp in [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) I pass it to `Date` JavaScript object as a string and JavaScript instantiate an object from it that holds the specified date and time. Example:

```
var datetime = new Date('2013-07-18T19:17:09+03:00');
```

This works on Google Chrome and I wonder if it will on most major browsers? If not what is the most compatible JavaScript time-format for Date object?
Thanks

Comment: The really most compatible is probably the UNIX epoch offset. Not really user friendly mind you.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like ISO 8601 as a date/time string format, mostly because it is easily readable (which may not be a concern for you). I don't think support for it in the JavaScript `Date` object works across all browsers though.

I usually end up using some version of the parsing code here: http://dansnetwork.com/javascript-iso8601rfc3339-date-parser/

Related question: [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par)