# Javascript Date conversion Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, date

I was looking for this very specific conversion which I couldnt find anywhere

```
var d = new Date("2014-12-25T18:30:00+0100");
console.log(d.toString());
```

the console.log returns an "Invalid Date"
The DateString is returned by the Facebook GraphAPI.

What am I doing wrong? can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Now that I fixed the API my output is kind of consfusing:

I tried splitting up the String

```
d.getDay()+'.'+d.getMonth()+'.'+d.getYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes();
```

it outputs

```
4.11.114 18:30
```

why?!

Comment: Is there more code elsewhere? This seems to be working fine in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: WHAT browser??? My guess IE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par

Comment: Chrome is my browser, but the String wasnt the problem ! Thanks for your help- My internal API didnt get the values properly

Comment: Edited my question with a new Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing those complicated date functions

```
d.getDate()+'.'+d.getMonth()+'.'+d.getYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes();
```

Do yourself a favour and include http://momentjs.com/ in your project. You can then simply take the date from the facebook api and format it with

```
moment("2014-12-25T18:30:00+0100").format("/* date format */");
```

[**See here for formating**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

SIDENOTE

When formating dates in plain javascript, you will have to add 1 month to your month - january is 0, that's why you get 4.11... instead of 4.12...

Comment: Please correct the d.getDay() to "d.getDate()" which returns the correct digit - then your answer is perfectly correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Change getYear() to getFullYear()

`d.getDay()+'.'+d.getMonth()+'.'+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes();`