# convert iso date to milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, iso, isodate

Can I convert iso date to milliseconds?
for example I want to convert this iso

```
2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000
```

to milliseconds.

Because I want to compare current date from the created date. And created date is an iso date.

Comment: What do you mean by "milliseconds" exactly? Milliseconds relative to which point in time? Do you mean a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: just like in yahoo api, date is shown by milliseconds `1328796537`, but in fb api, date is shown in iso `2012-02-10T13:18:45+0000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @mplungjan related, but not exact. I want to get the difference between the two times.

Comment: So use the link to translate them to dates first and do `date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()` - it is all you need

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Try this

```js
var date = new Date("11/21/1987 16:00:00"); // some mock date
var milliseconds = date.getTime(); 
// This will return you the number of milliseconds
// elapsed from January 1, 1970 
// if your date is less than that date, the value will be negative

console.log(milliseconds);
```

**EDIT**

You've provided an ISO date. It is also accepted by the constructor of the `Date` object

```js
var myDate = new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000");
var result = myDate.getTime();
console.log(result);
```

**Edit**

The best I've found is to get rid of the offset manually.

```js
var myDate = new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000");
var offset = myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

var withOffset = myDate.getTime();
var withoutOffset = withOffset - offset;
console.log(withOffset);
console.log(withoutOffset);
```

Seems working. As far as problems with converting ISO string into the `Date` object you may refer to the links provided.

**EDIT**

Fixed the bug with incorrect conversion to milliseconds according to Prasad19sara's comment.

Comment: Yes, Date will not parse on all browsers. [See my answer on related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par/5803041#5803041)

Comment: And see my comment on the answer under yours ;)

Comment: This does not work in Firefox `var myDate = new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000");
`

Comment: @mplungjan why you don't use [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/QkasD/27/)? I know this is cumbersome but anyway ))

Comment: uh... that's that capital "T" doing in there? That's why it doesn't work @mplungjan.

Comment: The T is an ISO date given by some systems. I remove it in another answer here at SO

Comment: this is a good solution. But offset should be multiplied by 60. 
var TIMEZONE_OFFSET = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;

Answer (score 41):

A shorthand of the previous solutions is

```
var myDate = +new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000");
```

It does an on the fly type conversion and directly outputs date in millisecond format.

Another way is also using parse method of Date util which only outputs EPOCH time in milliseconds.

```
var myDate = Date.parse("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000");
```

Comment: You have a little typo there, '+'

Comment: @stuart-siegler That's actually no typo, the '+' returns the Date in milliseconds.

Comment: @LordTribual "+new" returns the date in miliseconds?

Comment: @stuart-siegler Not specifically "+new" but the "+" does the trick and is a shorthand so-to-say. For example `+new Date()` returns `1447857230137` which is the time in milliseconds.

Comment: It is much clearer to explicitly construct a JavaScript Number object: `const dateMillis = Number(new Date('2017-09-26T20:24:18.801Z'))`, but `new Date('2017-09-26T20:24:18.801Z').getTime()` or `new Date('2017-09-26T20:24:18.801Z').valueOf()` is even more readable.

Answer (score 7):

Another option as of 2017 is to use `Date.parse()`. MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) points out, however, that it is unreliable prior to ES5.

```
var date = new Date(); // today's date and time in ISO format
var myDate = Date.parse(date);
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/cawrLc9u/) for more details.

Comment: The built–in parser is unreliable **after** ECMAScript 2011 also. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this in a single line

```
let ms = Date.parse('2019-05-15 07:11:10.673Z');
console.log(ms);//1557904270673
```

Comment: What is the opposite of this function!?

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to compare current date with `January 1, 1970`, you can get `January 1, 1970` by `new Date(0)`;

```
var date = new Date(); 
var myDate= date - new Date(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date()
console.log(" Date in MS last three digit = "+  date.getMilliseconds())
console.log(" MS = "+ Date.now())
```

Using this we can get date in milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to use Number object parser like this:

```js
let result = Number(new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000"));
let resultWithGetTime = (new Date("2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000")).getTime();
console.log(result);
console.log(resultWithGetTime);
```

This converts to milliseconds just like `getTime()` on `Date` object

Answer (score 2):

var date = new Date(date_string);
var milliseconds = date.getTime();

This worked for me!

Comment: how is this different from the top answer?

Answer (score 0):

if wants to convert UTC date to milliseconds
syntax : Date.UTC(year, month, ?day, ?hours, ?min, ?sec, ?milisec);
e.g : 
`date_in_mili = Date.UTC(2020, 07, 03, 03, 40, 40, 40);`
`console.log('miliseconds', date_in_mili);`

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone wants to **grab only the Time from** a ISO Date, following will be helpful. I was searching for that and I couldn't find a question for it. So in case some one sees will be helpful.

```
let isoDate = '2020-09-28T15:27:15+05:30';
let result = isoDate.match(/\d\d:\d\d/);
console.log(result[0]);
```

The output will be the only the time from isoDate which is,

```
15:27
```