# Date format conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I wondering what is the best way to convert a timestamp of this format -

```
2012-02-18 14:28:32
```

to a date presentation of this format -

```
Saturday Feb 2012 14:28:32
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: As for formatting to a final string I could suggest you [the following library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format). As far as the first part of the question is concerned you could refer to the [following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript/9229384)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript date functions are pretty bad... You have the option to convert to UTC http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_toutcstring

But if it was me, i would look into Datejs: http://www.datejs.com/ best javascript date api for me

Please take a look at the getting started with Datejs: http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/

Answer (score 3):

You must first define an array of the English words (Sunday, Monday, Feb, Mar, etc.):

```
var daysOfWeek = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
    monthsOfYear = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
```

To be able insert the extra `0` at the beginning of the minutes and seconds, define a padding function for the `String` prototype:

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function(padString,length){
    var toReturn = String(this);
    while(toReturn.length < length){
        toReturn = padString + toReturn;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Format the date and time like this:

```
var time = new Date(), formattedDate, formattedTime, wholeThing;
formattedDate = daysOfWeek[time.getDay()] + ", " + monthsOfYear[time.getMonth()] + " " + time.getDate() + ", " + time.getFullYear();
formattedTime = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes().padLeft("0",2) + time.getSeconds().padLeft("0",2);
```

You can get the whole thing by concatenating `formattedDate` and `formattedTime`, as in:

```
wholeThing = formattedDate + " " + formattedTime;
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`datejs`](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) which is rocks!

```
var mydate = Date.parse('2012-02-18 14:28:32');
var result = mydate.toString('dddd MMM yyyy h:mm:ss');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: ??? Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36
    at Number.toString (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:21

Comment: @PaoloBiavati that means you call `toString` on a number, not a Date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527109/javascript-date-tostring-radix-argument-error (use datejs).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using an external js library to do that. To my understanding, [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is the best date-time conversion library out there.

In this case, it does the job in one line. Just add the moment.js in you project and then do

```
var timestamp = '2012-02-18 14:28:32';
var formattedTime = moment(timestamp).format('dddd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss'); // Saturday Feb 2012 14:28:32
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScripts Date object is lacking methods for formatting. I would consider using an external library like [this one](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format). Seems it has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this blog it has enough dateformats:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format