# How to convert date to timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to convert date to timestamp, my input is `26-02-2012`. I used

```
new Date(myDate).getTime();
```

It says NaN.. Can any one tell how to convert this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343971/timestamp-conversion-javascript

Comment: you may want to take a look at the date.js library: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Did you use `Date(myDate).getTime()` (what you've marked up as code), or is the word "new" prior to it meant to be part of the code? The more effort you put in, the better the answers you get will be.

Comment: @rsbarro: Except it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore (and there are outstanding bugs). [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) seems quite good, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've used date.js and it's worked for what I've needed it for, but you're right it has not been actively worked on in some time. I will check out momentjs. Thanks!

Comment: @rsbarro: This is the one (a parsing bug) that bit me: http://jsbin.com/inudib The version used on the datejs.com home page is different from the latest "release" and doesn't have this problem (but has others that the latest "release" doesn't).

Comment: You need parenthesis around the `new Date()` ... So like, `(new Date("2022-03-02")).getTime()`

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Split the string into its parts and provide them directly to the Date constructor:

**Update:**

```js
var myDate = "26-02-2012";
myDate = myDate.split("-");
var newDate = new Date( myDate[2], myDate[1] - 1, myDate[0]);
console.log(newDate.getTime());
```

**Updated:**
Also, you can use a regular expression to split the string, for example:

```js
const dtStr = "26/02/2012";
const [d, m, y] = dtStr.split(/-|\//); // splits "26-02-2012" or "26/02/2012"
const date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
console.log(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Safari5, as it returns `NaN`. In Safari you have to use the other possible constructor `new Date(year, month, day);`, regarding this example: `new Date(myDate[2], myDate[1], myDate[0]);`

Comment: Instead of converting the date string from "European" to "American" format, it's better to convert it to ISO 8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DD`), which is guaranteed to be understood by `Date()`, and is, generally speaking, the most interoperable format for date strings.

Comment: Note: `new Date(newDate).getTime()` will produce a timestamp in millisecond resolution.

Comment: For seconds use:  `Math.floor(new Date(newDate).getTime() / 1000)`

Comment: C'mon, seriously they should really think of a better naming instead of getTime()!

Answer (score 99):

Try this function, it uses the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method and doesn't require any custom logic:

```
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
   return datum/1000;
}
alert(toTimestamp('02/13/2009 23:31:30'));
```

Comment: Using the built–in parser is not recommended.

Comment: @RobG can you please include an argument _why_ it is not recommended? This would add value and understanding to your comment.

Comment: @dimib—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/257182) to [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).

Comment: why have you chosen to use that date format? I want to understand you used mm/dd/yyyy, right? Why the reason? Does using a different format has an effect?

Comment: I would recommend adding a `Math.floor` around the `return datum/1000;` line to prevent a decimal timestamp as it would make no sense for one to leave out the decimals after attempting to remove the millisecond precision via dividing by 1000. You'd usually want to either leave it as it is in milliseconds (by omitting the `/1000`) or get the value in seconds in the form of a whole number (by wrapping it in a `Math.floor`).

Answer (score 54):

this refactored code will do it

```
let toTimestamp = strDate => Date.parse(strDate)
```

this works on all modern browsers except ie8-

Comment: Great answer. Note it creates a millisecond timestamp. For a timestamp with seconds accuracy you can `Date.parse(strDate) / 1000;` instead of `Date.parse(strDate)`.

Answer (score 27):

There are two problems here.
First, you can only call getTime on an instance of the date. You need to wrap new Date in brackets or assign it to variable.

Second, you need to pass it a string in a proper format.

Working example:

```
(new Date("2012-02-26")).getTime();
```

Comment: There's no need of wrapping the date instant in a bracket. Only a proper string format is required.

Answer (score 19):

UPDATE: In case you came here looking for **current** timestamp

```
Date.now(); //as suggested by Wilt
```

or

```
var date      = new Date();
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

or simply

```
new Date().getTime();
/* console.log(new Date().getTime()); */
```

Comment: Yes or simply: `Date.now()` which makes your two suggestions suddenly look very complicated. Visit for more details on this function [the documentation on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Answer (score 12):

You need just to reverse your date digit and change `-` with `,`:

```
new Date(2012,01,26).getTime(); // 02 becomes 01 because getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11)
```

In your case:

```
var myDate="26-02-2012";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
new Date(parseInt(myDate[2], 10), parseInt(myDate[1], 10) - 1 , parseInt(myDate[0]), 10).getTime();
```

P.S. UK locale does not matter here.

Comment: That date format is also invalid, and won't work reliably cross-browser and cross-locale (it doesn't, for instance, for me in Chrome with the UK locale). If you're going to suggest a format, suggest one that's actually documented to work.

Comment: I get the example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. I just forgot to put away the string. Now  it works.

Comment: Okay, at least now the code above isn't using an invalid date format -- it's just giving the wrong date, for two separate reasons. Above you've defined the date March 2nd, 2014 (you have the field order messed up). And if the fields were in the right order, you'd be defining the date **March** 26th, 2012 (month values start at zero). But as the OP has a string, not a series of numbers, it's not all that useful even if you addressed those issues.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for your suggestions. I fixed the code as you said converting the String to a Number. Merci.

Comment: The first code example is **still wrong**, and using `Number` on strings starting with a `0` is problematic on some engines -- use `parseInt` and specify a radix.

Comment: **Again**: The first code example is still wrong. With respect, this is not helpful, recommend just deleting and moving on -- or, of course, really rigorously thinking it through and double-checking yourself. Bad advice is usually worse than no advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9324/discussion-between-antojs-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: please note that in the second part it most certainly should be `parseInt(myDate[0], 10))` instead of `parseInt(myDate[0]), 10)`, otherwise 10 would not be the radix but the next argument of the `Date()` constructor, which is the hour

Comment: Finally got to a decent answer, but *parseInt* isn't necessary, just pass the values to the constructor (but still subtract 1 from the month number). :-)

Answer (score 8):

To convert (ISO) date to **Unix timestamp**, I ended up with a timestamp 3 characters longer than needed so my year was somewhere around 50k...

I had to devide it by 1000:
`new Date('2012-02-26').getTime() / 1000`

Answer (score 7):

**JUST A REMINDER**

```
Date.parse("2022-08-04T04:02:10.909Z")
// 1659585730909

Date.parse(new Date("2022-08-04T04:02:10.909Z"))
// 1659585730000 (milliseconds are ignored)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your string isn't in a format that the `Date` object is [specified to handle](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15). You'll have to parse it yourself, use a date parsing library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) or the older (and not currently maintained, as far as I can tell) [DateJS](http://datejs.com), or massage it into the correct format (e.g., `2012-02-29`) before asking `Date` to parse it.

Why you're getting `NaN`: When you ask `new Date(...)` to handle an invalid string, it returns a `Date` object which is set to an invalid date (`new Date("29-02-2012").toString()` returns `"Invalid date"`). Calling `getTime()` on a date object in this state returns `NaN`.

Comment: @benvds: Cool, thanks. Although I find the comment *"Also, it is non-destructive to the DOM"* a bit odd... I expect what they meant was that it doesn't change the `Date` object (which has nothing to do with the DOM).

Answer (score 4):

For those who wants to have readable timestamp in format of, `yyyymmddHHMMSS`

```
> (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^\d]/g,'')              // "20190220044724404"
> (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^\d]/g,'').slice(0, -3) // "20190220044724"
> (new Date()).toISOString().replace(/[^\d]/g,'').slice(0, -9) // "20190220"
```

Usage example: a backup file extension. `/my/path/my.file.js.20190220`

Comment: Be aware that toISOString converts your date to UTC, so might not always have the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

The below code will convert the current date into the timestamp.

```
var currentTimeStamp = Date.parse(new Date());
console.log(currentTimeStamp);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Date to timestamp
 * @param  string template
 * @param  string date
 * @return string
 * @example         datetotime("d-m-Y", "26-02-2012") return 1330207200000
 */
function datetotime(template, date){
    date = date.split( template[1] );
    template = template.split( template[1] );
    date = date[ template.indexOf('m') ]
        + "/" + date[ template.indexOf('d') ]
        + "/" + date[ template.indexOf('Y') ];

    return (new Date(date).getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is fine however Using react typescript would complain because of split('')
for me the method tha worked better was.

```
parseInt((new Date("2021-07-22").getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))
```

Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, it appears that some dates are stubborn, that is, even with a date format, like "2022-06-29 15:16:21", you still get null or NaN. I got to resolve mine by including a "T" in the empty space, that is:

```
const inputDate = "2022-06-29 15:16:21";
const newInputDate = inputDate.replace(" ", "T");

const timeStamp = new Date(newInputDate).getTime();
```

And this worked fine for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It should have been in this standard date format YYYY-MM-DD, to use below equation. You may have time along with example: 2020-04-24 16:51:56 or 2020-04-24T16:51:56+05:30. It will work fine but date format should like this YYYY-MM-DD only.

```
var myDate = "2020-04-24";
var timestamp = +new Date(myDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `valueOf` method

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am converting the current date to a timestamp and then I take the timestamp and convert it to the current date back, with us showing how to convert date to timestamp and timestamp to date.

```js
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.getTime();
console.log(timestamp) // 1654636718244

var actual = new Date(timestamp)
console.log(actual) // Tue Jun 07 2022 18:18:38 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

Comment: NOTE::

Date.parse("2022-08-04T04:02:10.909Z")
>> 1659585730909
   While    
Date.parse(new Date("2022-08-04T04:02:10.909Z"))
>> 1659585730000

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and accurate way would be to add the unary operator before the date

```js
console.log(`Time stamp is: ${Number(+new Date())}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers have been provided by other developers but in my own way, you can do this on the fly without creating any user defined function as follows:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse("26-02-2012".split('-').reverse().join('-'));
alert(timestamp); // returns 1330214400000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply performing some arithmetic on a `Date` object will return the timestamp as a `number`. This is useful for compact notation. I find this is the easiest way to remember, as the method also works for converting numbers cast as `string` types back to `number` types.

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(d, d * 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick if you need to add time also
`new Date('2021-07-22 07:47:05.842442+00').getTime()`

This would also work without Time
`new Date('2021-07-22 07:47:05.842442+00').getTime()`

This would also work but it won't Accept Time
`new Date('2021/07/22').getTime()`

And Lastly if all did not work use this
`new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

**Note for Month it the count starts at `0` so `Jan === 0` and `Dec === 11`**

Answer (score 0):

`+new Date(myDate)`
this should convert myDate to timeStamp

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

it that simple but you have to make sure to use **american** date format

```js
    function MygetTime(date){
return (new Date(date).getTime())
}
console.log(MygetTime("03-13-2023"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get my time stamp:
`Date.parse("2000-03-04 09:10:43")/1000;`

Answer (score 0):

**2024 UPDATE**

*No package needed*

```js
const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```