# Convert normal date to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

How can I convert normal date `2012.08.10` to unix timestamp in javascript?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2pWj/





I've seen many posts here that convert it in PHP, Ruby, etc... But I need to do this inside JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert date to timestamp in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you tried newDate.getTime() / 1000?

Comment: @LokiAstari yes, sorry. I did search but didn't find that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but `unix timestamp` is so fundamental to all the engineering and computer science. Wish there was built-in convenience method. Currently I'm using `Math.floor((+new Date()) / 1000);`

Comment: This worked fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72047159/8119511

Answer (score 412, accepted):

```
Math.floor(new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000)
```

Check the [JavaScript Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Math.floor it or its not a unix timestamp (it'll have a decimal)

Comment: @fguillen,Mooseman, I run and check this code. Once I convert unix timestamp to date it is giving me 2012.08.09 instead of 2012.08.10. Why is that..?

Comment: @user2584538, see my answer below. You must remove the decimals.

Comment: Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/2714931

Comment: Did something change since this answer? `.getTime()` returns UNIX timestamps at the time of writing this...

Comment: @Mentor UNIX time is measured in seconds, not milliseconds

Comment: why did you divide the result to 1000? because `getTime` will give you in ms

Answer (score 85):

```
parseInt((new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))
```

It's important to add the `toFixed(0)` to remove any decimals when dividing by 1000 to convert from milliseconds to seconds.

The `.getTime()` function returns the timestamp in milliseconds, but true unix timestamps are always in seconds.

Comment: just beware that this return a string, not a number.

Comment: Good point, changed answer to wrap with parseInt() to convert back to integer.

Comment: If performance matters, probably the better and more correct option is `Math.round` or `Math.floor`, rather than converting to a string and then back to an integer - that is: `Math.round(new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000)`

Comment: I haven't tested this out but just putting my two cents in here that I'm thinking this would be very slow compared to the current top method of `Math.floor(new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000)`. Reason is because this code plays with strings which in my mind would be more performance costly than just dealing with numbers.

Answer (score 41):

```js
var d = '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z';
console.log(new Date(d).valueOf()); // returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch
```

Comment: The only reason this isn't the accepted answer is because it returns the number of *milliseconds* where as the question is about unix timestamps, which are measured in *seconds*. So, you'll still have to do all of the division and Math.floor() that other answers suggest.

Answer (score 15):

You should check out the moment.js api, it is very easy to use and has lots of built in features.

I think for your problem, you could use something like this:

```
var unixTimestamp = moment('2012.08.10', 'YYYY.MM.DD').unix();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it using Date.parse() Method.

```
Date.parse($("#yourCustomDate).val())
```

Date.parse("03.03.2016")
output-> 1456959600000

Date.parse("2015-12-12")
output-> 1449878400000

Answer (score 11):

```
var date = new Date('2012.08.10');
var unixTimeStamp = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
```

In this case it's important to return only a whole number (so a simple division won't do), and also to only return actually elapsed seconds (that's why this code uses `Math.floor()` and not `Math.round()`).

Answer (score 7):

You can use **Date.parse()**, but the input formats that it accepts are implementation-dependent. However, if you can convert the date to **ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD)**, most implementations should understand it.

See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse).

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use the unary + operator

`(+new Date('2012.08.10')/1000).toFixed(0);`

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/ - look under Dates.

Comment: Just want to add two comments here: the unary add + operator is not needed, as `/` is already a math operator. Also, `toFixed` returns a string and not a number, in case the type is important..

Answer (score 1):

```
var datestr = '2012.08.10';
var timestamp = (new Date(datestr.split(".").join("-")).getTime())/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

After comparing timestamp with the one from PHP, none of the above seems correct for my timezone. The code below gave me same result as PHP which is most important for the project I am doing.

```js
function getTimeStamp(input) {
    var parts = input.trim().split(' ');
    var date = parts[0].split('-');
 var time = (parts[1] ? parts[1] : '00:00:00').split(':');

 // NOTE:: Month: 0 = January - 11 = December.
 var d = new Date(date[0],date[1]-1,date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);
 return d.getTime() / 1000;
}

// USAGE::
var start = getTimeStamp('2017-08-10');
var end = getTimeStamp('2017-08-10 23:59:59');

console.log(start + ' - ' + end);
```

I am using this on NodeJS, and we have timezone 'Australia/Sydney'. So, I had to add this on .env file:

```
TZ = 'Australia/Sydney'
```

Above is equivalent to:

```
process.env.TZ = 'Australia/Sydney'
```

Answer (score 1):

convert timestamp to unix timestamp.

`const date = 1513787412;
const unixDate = new Date(date * 1000);// Dec 20 2020 (object)`

to get the timeStamp after conversion 
`const TimeStamp = new Date(date*1000).getTime(); //1513787412000`

Answer (score 0):

Using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/unix-timestamp) library:

```
dayjs('2019-01-25').unix() // 1548381600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Math.round((new Date('specific date')).getTime() / 1000)  //it will return current timestamp in seconds
```