# Convert dijit/form/DateTextBox into UNIX timestamp

Tags: javascript, dojo, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Retrieved DateTextBox value looks like:

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 17:17:33 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

What is the best way to convert this into UNIX timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var unixtime = Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35").getTime()/1000

Comment: its an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp