# Javascript / Nodejs excute shell script and pass variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

I need to execute some shell scripts along my project:

```
restoreBackup(timestamp) {
  return runCommand(`backup_restore.sh ${timestamp}`);
},
```

The timestamp has to be passed to the script in the form of a unix timestamp.
e.g. 1513252423
The Timestamp is set or passed:

```
restoreBackup(timestamp,callback) {
    backup.restoreBackup(timestamp)
      .then(callback)
      .catch(err => callback(err));
  }
```

Problem is that my current solution doesn't work, it is kind of derived from the call I use directly on bash. The timestamp is not passed as unix time, but converted to a string, this is the output in the node console:

```
Running cmd: /home/essentim/manager/scripts/backup_restore.sh Thu Dec 14 2017 11:53:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)
error handler:
"/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected"
```

Any Idea how to solve this in this case?

Comment: can you log your timestamp and show?

Comment: Not sure I follow, what do you mean by "my current solution doesn't work"? What timestamp are you passing and what timestamp is that command receiving?

Comment: the problem is it seems that ${timestamp} does not pass the unix time stamp it kind of makes a string like "14 December 2017 1X:XX:XX" out of it.

Comment: Show the code where you set the value of timestamp.  Then show the value of timestamp you call, what value you get in the function.

Comment: restoreBackup(timestamp,callback) {
    backup.restoreBackup(timestamp)
      .then(callback)
      .catch(err => callback(err));
  }

Answer (score 0):

this is my workaround, which is working for now!

```
restoreBackup(timestamp) {
    timename = new Date(timestamp).getTime()/1000;
    return runCommand(`backup_restore.sh ${timename}`);
  },
```

took it from: [Convert normal date to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp/11893157)

Thx