# Datetime to integer in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I have my datetimestamp in the below formats -

```
2019-01-30 (21:00:00.000) CST
2019-01-31 (09:00:00.000) CST
```

I need to convert the above dates to integers like below -

```
75600000
32400000
```

I need to implement this in angular component to perform further mathematical operations. Assistance please?

Comment: Add the code you have tried to solve this that isn't working for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert normal date to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: i wonder why this question is negatively rated. I searched for hours and found solution provided here helped me. The solution even working fine on html page when used under interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple + prefix will suffice.

```
e.g.

let date = new Date();//Fri Feb 01 2019 07:19:00 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time)

let intDate = +new Date();//1548984868016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getTime()`.

For example,

```html
new Date(dateStr).getTime();
```