# How to convert user-defined datetime to milliseconds in typescript or javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a datetime in typescript as : `"Sep 12, 2019 15:22:18 PM"` . How to convert this datetime to milliseconds using typescript / javascript ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

> var date = new Date("Sep 12, 2019 15:22:18".replace('PM',''));

Note: The reason to replace `PM` is because your date format is not correct it's showing 24 hour format but still adding `PM`.