# how can I change the counting time to unix time stamp?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I want to get the expiration time of a product of webpage and change it to unix time using javascript date methods....

```
  var expiration = document.querySelector('span#bigDealTimer1');
  //with this selector I can get the time-counter.

  expiration = expiration && expiration.innerText;
```

how can i change the expiration time in the span to unix Time ?
(time is decreasing to zero)

Comment: expiration is in seconds ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert normal date to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't know what kind of format the date/time will be in, there's the standard `Date` library you can use for parsing your string date value to a UNIX timestamp.

```
const unixTimeZero = Date.parse('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
```

Ref - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse