# Javascript date to timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I know there are numerous ways to go about this, but I'm dealing with date formatted as such:

"2021-01-06T16:24:34Z"

How do I convert this to a timestamp that represent post unix epoch with Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert normal date to unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the date, then divide the resulting number by 1000 to have it in seconds.

To parse it, you just need to remove the `T` and the `Z`.

```js
let dateString = "2021-01-06T16:24:34Z";

let dateForDateParsing = dateString.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "");
console.log(dateForDateParsing);

let UnixTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date(dateForDateParsing) / 1000);
console.log(UnixTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Date("2021-01-06T16:24:34Z").getTime() / 1000
```