# Javascript get time in unix from a unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, time, unix-timestamp

How can I extract time only as a unix number from a unix timestamp?
For example:

```
const timeStamp = 1671682809 // Thursday, December 22, 2022 11:20:09 AM GMT+07:00
const unixTimeOnly = extractTime(timeStamp) // return a unix number that represents "11:20:09"
```

Thank you!

Comment: assuming the time is "00:00:00" (midnight), what this number is going to be?

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11893157/9078341

Comment: `+07:00` is only in your comments, not in the data.  Is the *local* time zone always applicable?  Also, [What have you tried?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by subtracting the same date, with the clock set to midnight:

```js
const timeStamp = 1671682809;
const date = new Date(timeStamp * 1000);
const midnightDate = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
const justHMS = date - midnightDate;
// you may want to divide this number how you wish if you're not working in milliseconds
console.log(justHMS);
```

Comment: This presumes the local time zone is applicable, and it also presumes that midnight exists on the day in question in the local time zone.  Yes, there are days without midnight - when a time zone has a forward transition that skips from 00:00 to 01:00, such as start of DST in Cuba (and others).