# Parsing ISO8601-like date in JavaScript: new Date() doesn't work across browsers

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser

How do I convert a date string coming from a database into a new Date() object?

If I do the following:

```
var x = new Date('2013-11-05 11:01:46:0');
alert(x);
```

It works in Chrome, but in Safari it gives me the string "Invalid Date".
[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/bUKFj/)

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript/9873379#9873379), tho it's not the same.

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/): `moment('2013-11-05 11:01:46:0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:S')` (then `toDate()` to get a Date object)

Comment: use a good pick up line.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe, I had to explain to my co-worker why I was laughing out loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of strings accepted by `new Date(string)` is implementation-dependent.  If the browser correctly implements the ES5 specification, however, [a strict subset of legal ISO 8601 strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) should be accepted.  Basically, you need to use UTC instead of local time, put a "T" instead of a space between the date and time, use a decimal point instead of a colon between integral and fractional seconds, and append a "Z" on the end of the whole thing:

```
2013-11-05T11:01:46.000Z
```

Perhaps you can get your database to output the dates in that format; otherwise, you should look into a third-party library, such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Wow.  Well, at least I know what to deal with now.  Thank you Mark!