# BST date string to javascript date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

How can I convert the BST date string to Javascript date object?

The follwing code gives me error for BST but works for other timezone

```
var data='Tue Apr 28 16:15:22 BST 2015';
var date = new Date(data);
console.log(date)
```

Output

```
Invalid Date
```

```js
var data='Tue Apr 28 16:15:22 BST 2015';
var date = new Date(data);
console.log(date)

var data2='Fri Mar 27 11:53:50 GMT 2015'
var date2 = new Date(data2);
console.log(date2)
```

Comment: By _BST_ I assume you mean _GMT+1_ ? Also, why is your time between your day and year?

Comment: It looks like you're relying on the browser specific date string parsing - i had a similar issue a while ago. If nobody else beat me to it I'll post when I get into work.

Comment: Related: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797608/parsing-iso8601-like-date-in-javascript-new-date-doesnt-work-across-browsers).  Also check out [this](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) chart showing issues with Javascript parsing dates from strings compatibility across browsers. In general, I recommend steering away from the default Date(String) constructor and go with a library or different constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't rely on *Date* to know timezone names
2. Don't mix a *date* with a *time*; the year should be before the time, the timezone should be the very last thing

Putting these together

```
var timezone_map = {
    'BST': 'GMT+0100'
};

function re_order(str) {
    var re = /^(\w+) (\w+) (\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) (\w+) (\d\d\d\d)$/;
    return str.replace(re, function ($0, day, month, date, time, zone, year) {
        return day + ' ' + month + ' ' + date + ' ' + year + ' ' + time + ' ' + (timezone_map[zone] || zone);
    });
}

new Date(re_order('Tue Apr 28 16:15:22 BST 2015'));
// Tue Apr 28 2015 16:15:22 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```