# Get time stamp only for date and vice versa

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

I have searched in SO and did not find my answer.

Here is my query , In javascript we generally generate time stamp like below

```
Date.now()
```

which outputs something like `1424592736769`

But this value changes each time , since time is associated with it.

For example Suppose I generate timestamp today and store in database....after few days If I enter date in format like `2012, 01, 1` , I should be able to get the same time stamp.

What I tried

```
//got time stamp 
var a = Date.now() / 1000000 | 0
var d = Date(a);
console.log(d);
```

// and now based on the var a , I can be generate the timestamp based on specifying dateformat 
I know its wrong , some one guide me please.

P.S  : I do this operation because I wanted to store a **data** on `particular date` as time stamp in database and modify those **data** later based on `that particular date` via timestamp.

For example my db should look like this

```
DAY         DATA
------------------
432324234 - 1000 rs //day1 data
767677657 - 2000 rs //day2 data
```

P.s : no one understood my question , To be more clear

I need to get todays date for example (feb 22 2015) as time stamp , After few days if I use Date(2015,01,22) , I must get the same time stamp generated on feb 22 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I'm understanding what you're trying to do, getting rid of the `new` keyword like so will set `d` to a `Date` object of timestamp `a`:

```
//got time stamp 
var a = Date.now() / 1000000 | 0
var d = Date(a);
console.log(d);
```

**EDIT**
Per this article: [convert date to timestamp in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript) to get a timestamp from a date do this:

```
var timestamp = new Date(myDate).getTime();
```

Comment: Do you just want the timestamp outputted? In that case just `d=a;`

Comment: please see my P.s Section , Suppose I generate timestamp today and store in database....after few days If I enter date in format like 2012, 01, 1 , I should be able to get the same time stamp

Comment: Hey yea , I guess your edit is the way to go  , Btw is this timestamp generated is global ? or change via location ?

Comment: Universal time, so global. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 1):

```
a = new Date(Date.now());
d = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()).getTime();
```

> I need to get todays date for example (feb 22 2015) as time stamp , After few days if I use Date(2015,22,2) , I must get the same time stamp generated on feb 22 2015

Be careful that the constructor format is Date(yyyy,mm,dd) so for today: Date(2015,02,22).

Comment: I need to get todays date(feb 22 2015) as time stamp , After few days if I use Date(2015,22,2) , I must get the same time stamp generated on feb 22 2015

Comment: Ah, do you want to have access just with the date, and your problem is, that you also would have to know hour, minute and second, since this is also stored in the number?
If this is your problem I suggest, that you use the link I gave you and save the day, the month and the year in the database, not the large number.

Comment: This stores just the current date always with time 00:00:00 in d. (22.02.2015 00:00:00). So you can find it with Date(2015,22,2).

d = new Date();
a = new Date(Date.now());
d.setFullYear(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());

Comment: hey +1 for your effort , But when I run your code , It displays different timestamp each time...I am gonna accept winhouse answer

Comment: see my edit. You have to use Date(2015,02,22), not Date(2015,22,02).
You always should get something like 'Sun Feb 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Normaltime (Mexico))'

Comment: Thats typo problem sorry...new Date(2015,01,22).getTime(); --> this is wat  i need , this always prints same time stamp...but when i run ur code it always print different timestamp..

Comment: Ok, now I see what you needed.
Save d from my post in the database, and to read it, search for Date(2015,02,22).getTime().
Of course date number in my code alwys changes, time is running... =)

Comment: yea time is running in your code , I wanted without time , just date :) thanks for your help