# django : how to read a date from javascript to python function

Tags: javascript, django, datetime

in my javascript file, I have a function

```
function saveMyData(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {

montitre = event.title;
mondepart = event.start;
mafin = event.end;`

$.getJSON("{% url events_drag %}", {'title': montitre, 'start': mondepart,
 'end': mafin},  function(data) {
 });
 }
```

if i put a message alert inside the function

```
alert(mafin);
```

I display :

```
Tue Aug 04 2015 16:00:00 GMT+0200
```

I want to send `mafin` to a python function with `getJSON` and read `mafin` with this code :

```
def eventsdrag(request):
    end = float(request.GET.get('end'))
    end = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(end)
```

How to convert `'Tue Aug 04 2015 16:00:00 GMT+0200'` in a number and read this number with `request.GET.get`?

Comment: Convert your `mafin` to a timestamp before sending it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: What have you tried? solutions you'll get on here about how to parse date times in python are the same as you'd get on google.