# Covert <input type="date" ng-model="jobDueDate"> to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to elegantly convert the value of this particular form field (input type="date") to a UNIX timestamp?

`console.log($scope.jobDueDate)` gives me "Wed Jun 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" and I really don't want to define a dictionary mapping months to numbers.

Comment: That's just the string representation of a `Date` object. You can simply use `$scope.jobDueDate.valueOf()` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873379/4963159)

```
$scope.jobDueDate.getTime()
```

EDIT:

getTime would give you milliseconds, which you then need to divide by 1000

```
$scope.jobDueDate.getTime()/1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var unixtime = Date.parse($scope.jobDueDate)/1000;
```

Explanation:
`Date.parse($scope.jobDueDate)` Gives time in milliseconds since 1970. So you divide by a 1000 to get time in seconds.