# Javascript 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' to timestamp

Tags: javascript

I want to convert datetime like '2015-05-01 05:13:43' into timestamp.
    Is there Any way to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: you can try `moment.js` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: I want a solution in core javascript without any library like 'moment.js'

Comment: Can you at least show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: @KishorJadhav, It is not working for scenario like 'mm;hh:ss'

Answer (score 4):

With pure JS you can try with:

```
new Date(Date.parse('2015-05-01 05:13:43+0000')).getTime() / 1000
```

It's important to add `+0000` at the end of the string - otherwise browser will use your local timezone and add/remove few hours from the result.

`getTime` method gives you time in ms - so we have to divide it by `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it!

```
let dateToConvert = '2015-05-01 05:13:43'
let date = new Date(dateToConvert)
let timestamp = date.getTime()
```

Comment: This method is not accurate.