# How to pass an Instant from a javascript app to a spring-data-rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a spring-data-rest API and I create a query like so:

```
@Query("SELECT at FROM Transaction at WHERE at.transactionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end")
Page<AssetsTransaction> findAllByDates(
    @Param("start") Instant start,
    @Param("end") Instant end,
    Pageable pageable);
```

Where Transaction.transactionDate is an Instant type.
how I should pass a date from a javascript app?

Answer (score 0):

Typically timestamps are stored/transferred/etc. in one of two ways:

### [UNIX timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

This is just a number representing the number of seconds from a fixed time in the past (known as the *UNIX epoch*).

Java has the [`Instant#getEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--) method to obtain this value, and the [`Instant.ofEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) static method to create an `Instant` object from a timestamp.

Javascript has the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type which can be instantiated from a timestamp (`new Date(timestamp * 1000)`), and transformed into a timestamp [with difficulty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9873197/1813169).

### [ISO 8601 strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

This is just regular ASCII text with a standardised format, for example:

```
2018-11-21T22:25:58+00:00
```

You gain the advantage of timezone support with this method.

Java uses [`Instant#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) to get an ISO 8601 string, and this slightly more verbose method to convert back:

```java
Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(string));
```

Javascript does not have native support for timezones, but it can still produce an ISO-compliant string with [`Date#toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and parse it back with the static [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Whichever way you go, you may wish to use an additional library on the javascript side to gain more control over your timestamps, if this is important to you.