# How to filter user data between 2 date range (timeStamp)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an Array of Object, where Array contains user details, such as Username, age, and timestamp. I want to filter the user from a particular date to a particular date with the help of timestamp

```
state = {
    result: [
      { userName: 'Rita', age: 19, timeStamp: '1570442597' },
      { userName: 'Rohan', age: 29, timeStamp: '1570442582' },
      { userName: 'Aadi', age: 24, timeStamp: '1569905303' },
      { userName: 'Naveen', age: 26, timeStamp: '1569904463' },
      { userName: 'Richa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569869577' },
      { userName: 'Reena', age: 30, timeStamp: '1569869487' },
      { userName: 'Dipak', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569866667' },
      { userName: 'Deepa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569849971' },
      { userName: 'Rohan', age: 29, timeStamp: '1570442582' },
      { userName: 'Aadi', age: 24, timeStamp: '1569905303' },
      { userName: 'Naveen', age: 26, timeStamp: '1529904463' },
      { userName: 'Richa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569863577' },
      { userName: 'Reena', age: 30, timeStamp: '1562869487' },
      { userName: 'Dipak', age: 20, timeStamp: '1564866667' },
      { userName: 'Deepa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1469849971' },
    ],
  };



{this.state.result.map(user => {
          const date = new Date(user.timeStamp * 1000);
          const dd = date.toDateString();
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                padding: 12,
                margin: 4,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                borderRadius: 4,
              }}>
              <Text>{user.userName}</Text>
              <Text>{dd}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
```

I except the output of (Mon Sep 30, 2019, to Mon Oct 07, 2019)

to be

Rohan
Mon Oct 07 2019

Aadi
Tue Oct 01 2019

Naveen
Tue Oct 01 2019

Richa
Tue Oct 01 2019

Reena
Tue Oct 01 2019

Comment: convert date to timestamp, compare and sort, print. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to filter the results between the first and and eightth of october (both midnight) inclusive.

We can create timestamps for these dates [this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/parse):

```
const min = Date.parse('2019-10-01');

const max = Date.parse('2019-10-08');
```

Then the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) method will come to help:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    result: [
      { userName: 'Rita', age: 19, timeStamp: '1570442597' },
      { userName: 'Rohan', age: 29, timeStamp: '1570442582' },
      { userName: 'Aadi', age: 24, timeStamp: '1569905303' },
      { userName: 'Naveen', age: 26, timeStamp: '1569904463' },
      { userName: 'Richa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569869577' },
      { userName: 'Reena', age: 30, timeStamp: '1569869487' },
      { userName: 'Dipak', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569866667' },
      { userName: 'Deepa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569849971' },
      { userName: 'Rohan', age: 29, timeStamp: '1570442582' },
      { userName: 'Aadi', age: 24, timeStamp: '1569905303' },
      { userName: 'Naveen', age: 26, timeStamp: '1529904463' },
      { userName: 'Richa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1569863577' },
      { userName: 'Reena', age: 30, timeStamp: '1562869487' },
      { userName: 'Dipak', age: 20, timeStamp: '1564866667' },
      { userName: 'Deepa', age: 20, timeStamp: '1469849971' },
    ],
  };


  render() {
    
    const min = Date.parse('2019-10-01');

    const max = Date.parse('2019-10-08');

    return this.state.result.filter(
      user => (user.timeStamp * 1000) >= min && (user.timeStamp * 1000) <= max
    ).map(
      user => {
        const date = new Date(user.timeStamp * 1000);
        const dd = date.toDateString();

        return (
          <p
            style={{
              padding: 12,
              margin: 4,
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderRadius: 4,
            }}
          >
            <span>{user.userName}</span>
            &nbsp;
            <span>{dd}</span>
          </p>
        );
      }
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The data has duplicates but it does not seem to be the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly a filter function for arrays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

So in your case,

```
const upperLimit = 1469849971; // u can convert a Date into unix time
const lowerLimit = 1469809971;
const filteredUsers = this.state.result.filter(user => lowerLimit <= user.timeStamp && user.timeStamp <= upperLimit);

// TODO your render using filteredUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this....

```
const filteredData = this.state.result.filter(data => new Date(data.timestamp) >= new Date("09/30/2019") && new Date(data.timestamp) <= new Date("10/07/2019"))
```