# How to add days to javascript unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript

How to add days to javascript unix  timestamp?

We can get the current time in timestamp using the following method:

```
Date.now()
```

Following is the method for adding days to a date.

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

console.log(date.addDays(5));
```

But this method does not return a unix  timestamp.

How can I add days to a unix  timestamp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date to timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this directly from the date object rather than manually using regex to parse the string?

Comment: What I'm saying is that how can I add days directly to the initial timestamp?

Comment: For example ```Date.now() + days```

Comment: Such that it returns a timestamp rather than a date string.

Comment: This is what I want. Please try to understand the situation first. Please.

Comment: Timestamp in milliseconds ,  like this ... 20180203073000

Comment: I didn't knew that you got confused. Normally we use timestamp for this long number and not date strings.

Comment: @ChrisG Timestamp in programmer language commonly refers to unix timestamps, which count the milliseconds that have passed since January 1st, 1970.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. In milliseconds. That's it. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes Unix Timestamps.

Comment: Can you help me with that? Show some code.

Comment: `Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { return this.setTime(this.getTime() + (86400000 * days)); }`

Comment: `const date = new Date; const time = date.addDays(5); const unix = time / 1000;`