# How can I save this DatePicker to firestore in a timestamp format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, datepicker

I wanted to save it in a firestore but currently it saves like this `1/20/2021`

```
const [seconDate, setSecondDate] = useState(new Date());

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                          <DatePicker
                            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                            value={secondDate}
                            onChange={setSeconDate}
                            fullWidth
                            id="date-picker-inline"
               
                          />
                        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting to firebase, process the date [like so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp)

```
const dateArray = seconDate.split('/');
const dateFormatted = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[0]);
const timestamp = dateFormatted.getTime();
console.log(timestamp);
```