# How to convert a date dd/mm/yyyy into the date object format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I have a date string which looks like :

```
const date =  "23/03/2022"
```

and I am trying to convert into the

```
Tue Mar 23 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I tried using `new Date(date)` not able to do it .

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Here you can find the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp#:~:text=Split%20the%20string,Update%3A)

Comment: `const d = new Date(date.split("/").reverse().map((v,n)=>+v-n%2));`