# JavaScript Date.toString() radix argument error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why won't the following code output my date to string!?

```
var d1 = Date.parse('10/29/1990 12:00:00 AM');
console.log(d1.toString('dd/MM/yyyy'));
```

The error is:

> Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and
>   36

Just trying to format the date...

Comment: JavaScript dates can't be formatted that way unless you're trying to use some fancy add-on library (in which case, it doesn't appear to be working :-)

Comment: @Pointy I was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript How do you recommend I format the date?

Comment: have you tried [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or are you using it allready?

Comment: @JanHommes no, but honestly; I've worked with javscripts datetime object before and it didn't seem like a problem before.  I don't want to use an entire library for one new line of code :)

Comment: @user1477388 Read the comments on that question: the OP was mistaken about the formatting function. You either need to use a library or build the string from individual parts, like in the accepted answer of that question.

Comment: The answer you are linking to uses the [date time format library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format), without it that wont work.

Comment: I would recommer it. Datejs is really helpfull, excspecially if it comes to globalization. Have you tried 'toLocaleString()'?

Comment: I think I am just going to use `myDateStr.split(' ')[0]`.  That seems to work for now.  Gives me 10/29/1990.

Comment: @user1477388: But didn't you want to swap days and months? Otherwise `.slice(0, 10)` would be enough of course…

Comment: @Bergi You're right, but I only said that mistakenly.  10/29/1990 is what I wanted (that is the US format).  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `d1` is not a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but a number. [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns the milliseconds representation, you will need to feed that into `new Date` or use the `Date` constructor directly.

And because JavaScript does not have a native date-formatting function, there are only the implementation-dependent `toString` and `toLocalString`  and the standardized `toISOString` and `toUTCString` (though not supported in older IE). Instead, you will have to do the formatting manually by getting the single components and concatenating them. Luckily, [there's a bunch of libaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632212/1048572) to help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `Date.prototype.toString` method takes no parameters (like formatting and such).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Using `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString` might help: `d1.toLocaleDateString('en')` works for me, but check out all the fine-print here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: It's not the Date `toString` method he is calling…