# How to set up a SharePoint filter based on Today (Hours & Minutes)?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a SharePoint list for an event that we are hosting. During the day we have several sessions that repeat in different rooms. I created an entry for each seat available for each session. The filter hides if a seat is taken. Furthermore, I have a column that shows session start time. Another calculated column that shows Sign Up available till (They can signup til l0 mins before the session)

However I cannot get a filtered view to show only upcoming sessions (10 mins or more from now). If I try [TODAY] it hides everything for that day. I need something the dynamically shows available sessions 10 mins or more from now. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Not an easy way around. But if you create a calculated column converting datetime to Minutes/seconds.
Now you a create a list view in designer and filter it by this calculated column (greater than filter param). You can pass the filter value from query string. Now the place where you provide the url to this page, you can generate minutes/seconds value based on current time(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript) and pass this value in query string. http:// < your list view page >?calVal=< value >