# NodeJS + MongoSkin + Timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

There's a handful of posts on inserting timestamps into Mongodb via MongoSkin, but nothing on the return end (other than pulling date from ObjectID).

After running findOne (which includes a MongoDate field), console-log reads the data field as ISO date, but is there an internal function that pulls the ->sec / timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript - Does this help?

Comment: @BatScream that method works, but is there a method directly from MongoDB driver?

Comment: You need to aggregate and project fields using the available date operators. - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/

Comment: @BatScream I wouldn't want to aggregate the data (via command), it should be a simple find query / cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `new Date( response.Date ).getTime()`