# Convert Date.now() to Milliseconds in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having a lot of trouble doing something that seems obvious. I have a date:

```
Date.now()
```

I want it in milliseconds from epoch. I cannot get that to work. I have tried:

```
Date.now().getTime();
(Date.now()).getTime();
Date.now().getMilliseconds();
(Date.now()).getMilliseconds();

var date = Date.now();
var ms = date.getTime();
var ms = date.getMilliseconds();
```

All of these fail because apparently [getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript) and [getMilliseconds()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp) (which I don't think is the correct approach anyways) are apparently not functions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Date.now()` already returns ms from epoch, not a Date object...

`Date.now` is a method in the Date namespace<sup>1</sup>, same as `Math.random` is for Math.
`Date` (unlike Math) is also a constructor. Used like `new Date()`, it will return a Date object.

<sup>1. A property of `Date`, which is a function/object</sup>

Answer (score 8):

You already have the value you want.

```
var numberOfMillisecondsSinceEpoch = Date.now();
```

You're attempting to call methods on a Date object, such as you'd get for the current date by calling `new Date()`. That's not necessary or appropriate if you're using `Date.now()`, which returns a number instead.

For platforms that don't provide `Date.now()`, you can convert the current Date object to a number to get the same value.

```
var numberOfMillisecondsSinceEpoch = Number(new Date());
```

```
Number(new Date()) === Date.now() // if your system is quick enough
```