# Internet date and time format to Unix timestamp and vice versa

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have date and time in the below Internet Date and Time Format

```
2020-07-06T06:48:08+0000
2020-07-07T10:02:45+0000
```

I need to convert this to Unix timestamp using javascript.

Once done, I need to then convert the Unix timestamp back to Internet Date and Time Format

```
1585859757
1585507012
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert iso date to milliseconds in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript)

Comment: Use the `Date` constructor. Notice that JS uses milliseconds since epoch, not seconds, so you'll have to multiply/divide accordingly.

Comment: divite by 1000 i guess ?