# How to convert user date to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date, date-conversion

For now I'm using this long method to convert user input in format: `DD.MM.YY HH:mm` to milliseconds.

```js
let day = date.substring(0, 2);
let mth = date.substring(3, 5);
let yr = date.substring(6, 10);
let hr = date.substring(11, 13);
let min = date.substring(14, 16);

let d = yr + "-" + mth + "-" + day + "T" + hr + ":" + min + ":00.000+02:00";
d = new Date(d).getTime();
```

Is there any easier, preferable way to do this? I've read about ISO dates and other norms but I haven't found anything that includes both day/month/year and hours/minutes without unnecessary milliseconds and time zones.

I'm not expert in js dates so be understanding. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Date` object in javascript is already based in milliseconds. So all you need is `date.now()`. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I think your question was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229213/convert-iso-date-to-milliseconds-in-javascript) thread

Comment: Yes. Given a timestamp like "2022.04.15 13:52" you could use `let [yr, mth, day, hr, min] = dateString.split(/\D/); new Date(yr, mth-1, day, hr, min).getTime();`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Date.parse which parses a date string. The MDN website has a full write-up on it at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: method `now` actually returns the date in milliseconds

Comment: Yes, but he wanted to convert an existing date string.