# Parse custom Date from string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

I have a set of strings, all in similar form: 2012-05-31T00:00:00.0000000

All I want to pull from this is the year (2012), the month (05), and the day (31), then construct a javascript Date object from this data.

What is the best way to parse this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is using a regular expression, and passing the values to the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
function parseISODate(dateString) {
    var match = /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/.exec(dateString);
    return new Date(Number(match[1]), Number(match[2]) - 1, Number(match[3]));
}

console.log(parseISODate('2012-05-31T00:00:00.0000000'));
// Date {Thu May 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200}
```

Of course, you could always expand this to match the time as well...

Comment: I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property '1' of null" when I try to use this. I've verified that I'm not passing in a null string. Any idea why?

Comment: @rwhite: that means your string doesn't match the regular expression. What is the exact contents of the string? (Also, what browser are you using?)

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Firefox, both the most recent releases. If I do a document.write(myDateString), the page displays '2012-05-21T00:00:00.0000000'. Is there more junk that is slipping in there somehow?

Comment: Nevermind. This works perfectly. In the area where I was trying to use your code, I was outside the scope of my date variable. Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT (In UTC):

```
var origDate = new Date('2012-05-31T00:00:00.0000000');
var newDate = new Date(origDate.getUTCFullYear(), origDate.getUTCMonth(), origDate.getUTCDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's not cross-browser compatible; several of them won't parse a date in this format.

Comment: Please give an example of where this code is not cross-browser compatible.  I believe that this is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Well, IE up to 9, for example.  I know some people would argue that isn’t a major browser, but still...

Comment: Not sure where you are getting your information from but this is supported as far back as IE 7 (at least).

Comment: Have you actually tried your code?  I have. In IE9 Quirks Mode, `origDate` contains `NaN`.  IE9 in Standards Mode actually throws an "Invalid Date" error.

Comment: Actually, IE9 does support it, if you remove the `.0000000` bit.  IE7 and IE8 still choke on it, though.

Comment: This should work in all if you modify format the date string to '2012/05/31'