# library for ISO 8601 formatted duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, iso8601

I am looking for **javascript/jquery library** which can provide me the UI and functionality to select ISO 8601 formatted duration.

UI should contain multiple cascaded select box where user can select Month, Hours, Days, Week... defined in [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

Upon selection library should convert it into standard **ISO_8601** duration formatted code and vice versa.

*For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14934089/1835803

Answer (score 3):

Wrapped up a small library to help with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyduration

Example usage:

```js
import { parse, serialize } from 'tinyduration';
 
// Basic parsing
const durationObj = parse('P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
assert(durationObj, {
    years: 1,
    months: 2,
    days: 3,
    hours: 4,
    minutes: 5,
    seconds: 6
});
 
// Serialization
assert(serialize(durationObj), 'P1Y2M3DT4H5M6S');
```

You can install it using `npm install --save tinyduration` or `yarn add tinyduration`

HTH

Answer (score 2):

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is a popular time library for js, and there is a plugin available on github called [moment-interval](https://github.com/luisfarzati/moment-interval) that supports ISO 8601 durations

From the github readme

```
moment.duration(3, 'weeks').toISOString(); // "P3W"
moment.duration({days: 9, hours: 18}).toISOString(); // "P9DT18H"
```

See the moment-interval github page for more examples

Comment: great. This is what I am looking for. please also suggest me for UI library which provides UI so that it will reduce my work

Comment: I have referred UI and Functionality in both in the same question.

Comment: Moment is no longer maintained. Luxon does have 8601 parsing