# Parse duration format from PT0S or PT1H57M4S to 01:57:04 in Google Sheets/DataStudio

Tags: google-sheets

I'm exporting duration from clockify to google sheets, but keep getting duration in format unreadable by datastudio where I want to visualize data synced from clickify to sheets.

I tried sulution from below posts, but none of these works for me.
[Google Sheet formula to convert Youtube's API ISO 8601 duration format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561919/google-sheet-formula-to-convert-youtubes-api-iso-8601-duration-format)

Can you help me create a formula that would convert duration format from PT0S or PT1H57M4S to 01:57:04?

If you can please do it in this sheet, where I'm working in
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qPIUp2q9X3Wh7V1KMVgPeqCjF_r4d5wbjlzOTTUbGZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks before!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 1 / ( 
    iferror( regexextract(C1:C; "(\d+)H") / 24 ) + 
    iferror( regexextract(C1:C; "(\d+)M") / 24 / 60 ) + 
    iferror( regexextract(C1:C; "(\d+)S") / 24 / 60 / 60 ) 
  ) ^ -1 ) 
)
```

Format the result column as **Format > Number > Duration**. Note that durations of zero length are shown as blanks rather than `0`.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.