# Parsing a human readable time from an ISO-8601 formatted string using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, momentjs, iso8601

I have an ISO-8601 date of the form:

```
2014-02-02T15:00:00-0800
```

Can anyone demonstrate how to to extract a time of the form

```
3:00pm
```

Using moment.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

Comment: There's no moment.js solution in the referenced question.

Comment: have you checked the moment.js documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) you find `Parse` documentation. [Here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is `Format`. Combined together gives:

```
var dateAsString = '...';
moment.utc(dateAsString).format('h:mmA');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76Ued/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/76Ued/2/ <- this one uses `local()`

**EDIT**
Version considering Matt Johnson's hint:

```
var dateAsString = '...';
moment(dateAsString).format('h:mmA');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76Ued/13/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The formatting looks good but I'm getting unexpected results. For example I expected the output time in your example be 3:00pm and not 11:00pm.

Comment: 3pm is in your local time which is 11pm in Greenwich time. I think `.local()` prior to format will help. More info: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

Comment: Just do `moment(dateAsString)`.  There's no need to parse as utc if you're just going to convert back to local again.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks Matt, you should post it as an alternative answer while it answers better the question, imho.