# How to change DateTime model field representation in serializer?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, datetime-format

I want to make a view that will return some model objects in JSON. Everything is ok exception made for DateTimeField, that serializes raw value, not as represented in the template. How can I get the pretty value rather than raw as shown below ?

Model:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serialization:

```
serializers.serialize('json',
            list(Request.objects.filter(
                    id__gt=request.GET.get("last_id", 0)
                )[:MAX_REQUESTS])
        ),
```

Expected:

> June 19, 2015, 8:24 a.m.

Result:

> 2015-06-19T08:23:18.021Z

Comment: Create custom Encoder [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json), if you using json api, perhaps better is using [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: @Wolkodav can you provide an example how can I create this? The docs example isn't as clear as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can return JSON serialized data with `DateTime` fields in ISO format, then from your javascript, you can parse and format the dates as you need. See: [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

```
import json

json.dumps(your_requests, default=lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat') else obj)
```