# How to parse ISO string into Time and Date format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, iso, jsx

I have a string `"2016-01-01T00:20:50z"`. How can I parse the string into date and time format in Javascript? Such as for string date: `"2016-01-01"` and for string time format: `"20:50"`.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: @Gangz but doing new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z'), what would it return? It would be one string again and needs to be parsed to date and time format again?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend Datejs at "https://github.com/datejs/Datejs" for all things dealing with date and time. It can parse "2016-01-01T00:20:50Z" correctly (note the "z" has to be capital.)

Comment: not saying you are wrong, but https://github.com/moment/moment/ is used more often and is proven. Check it out.

Comment: @MichaelErickson Is there way to do with just with Javscript rather than using a framework?

Comment: @You I looked into moment js and looks useful, but I can't seem to find the exact example for my case. How would I parse string "2016-01-01T00:20:50z" into date: "2016-01-01" and time: "20:50"