# How to change ISO date to Standard JS Date?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to change an ISO date to a Standard JS Date format. The JS format I am referring to is:

```
Mon `Jul 20 2020 14:29:52 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript

Comment: Do you want a string? Or a Date object itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

Comment: moment.js is a great tool for dealing with dates in JS

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ISO_DATE = '2020-07-14T23:02:27.713Z';

function formatDate(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  
  return date.toString();
};

console.log(formatDate(ISO_DATE));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```js
let isoDate = "2020-07-20T14:29:52Z";
var myDate = new Date(isoDate);

console.log(myDate.toString());   // Mon Jul 20 2020 17:29:52 GMT+0300 ( (your time zone)

console.log("Back to ISO Date: ", myDate .toISOString());
```

If you want to convert it back to ISO Date use:

console.log(myDate.toISOString());