# Convert date to string in Angular

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on an Angular webui project. Currently I have to get a value from a data-document.json which is of type date but I need to display it as a string. How would I be able to achieve this?

```
"FACD_Dispatch_DateTime": "2022-01-19T16:46:03.959",
```

this is the way that I've been trying:

```
map(([d]) => {

           let myDate: string;
          if (d?.value) {
            myDate = d.value;
          }
```

but terminal returns the error: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

well `"FACD_Dispatch_DateTime": "2022-01-19T16:46:03.959"` is not a Date, but a string. Anyway:

```js
let myDate: Date;
if (d?.value) {
  myDate = d.value;
}
```

then you can display it in your HTML:

```html
<h1> Day: {{myDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}} Time: {{myDate | date:'HH:mm'}}</h1>
```

Comment: This is the error that I get from terminal when I try to retrieve it as is:

Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: so i edited my answer. anyway myDate must be of type Date `let myDate:Date`... but what is `d`? try to `console.log(d)`