# Need to transform timestamp to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: javascript

I have a date value in my React app that's returned from MySQL as a string in this format:

```
"2012-03-04T00:00:00.000+00:00"
```

The date gets transformed, using moment, to this format:

```
03/04/2012
```

Using moment, this is simple:

```
moment(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

But I'd like to change this, since moment is [no longer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) maintained.

Is there a simple way to do this transformation with some built-in javascript date function?

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript) don't help here, as they include no details on formatting the resulting date the way I need it.

Comment: Have a look at [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)  No need for Moment.

Comment: That gives me 3/4/2012,12:00:00 AM (after creating a new Date() from my string, then applying toLocaleDateString to it).

Comment: I just tried it and the output is exactly what you asked for and with just one line of code:  Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6adk79gs/)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I needed the 'en-US'. But I would like to end up with 2 character MM and DD values. That's part of why I'm so confused as to why this question was immediately closed as a "duplicate". None of those other answers addresses this use case with that resulting format.

Comment: See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtn50zjh/) for 2 character MM and DD.  The method  has many options to format the date however you want.

Comment: That works great! If you're interested in creating this as an answer I would switch my accepted answer to this approach, as it's more straightforward than the one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
const date = new Date("2019-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00")
const year = date.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')
const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
const formatted = `${month}/${day}/${year}`
console.log(formatted)
```

But I would just another library like `date-fns` or `dayjs`

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I’m stumped as to why this question was closed as a duplicate. None of the “duplicate” questions shows how to end up with this format.